# When do the first neurons appear in humans?

Tags: cell-biology, embryology, neuron

According to this

[Neural Plate](https://discovery.lifemapsc.com/in-vivo-development/neural-ectoderm/neural-plate)

The neural plate appears in day 18 in humans (very specific).

and according to this

[Neural Plate (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_plate)

> The progenitor cells that make up the precursors to neural tissues in
>   the neural plate are called neuroepithelial cells.

And according to this

[Neuroepithelial cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroepithelial_cell)

> Neuroepithelial cells are the stem cells of the central nervous
>   system, known as neural stem cells, and generate the intermediate
>   progenitor cells known as radial glial cells, that differentiate into
>   neurons and glia in the process of neurogenesis

So, if it's known when the cells which are precursors of neurons appear, I suppose it should be known when the first neurons appear, but I can't find information about it.

When do the first neurons appear in humans?

Comment: define a neuron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, olfactory axons and GnRH producing neurons are among the first neurons that migrate from neural crest at around 39th day of gestation in humans ([Cassoni et al., 2016](https://dx.doi.org/10.1242/dev.139444)).

> In rodents, early GnRH neurons migrate together with a heterogeneous
>   coalescence of placode-derived and neural crest-derived migratory
>   cells (Forni et al., 2011) and olfactory axons, collectively called
>   the ‘migratory mass’ (MM) (Miller et al., 2010; Valverde et al.,
>   1992). This cell migration precedes the targeting of olfactory sensory
>   axons to the developing olfactory bulb (OB). The existence of a
>   similar MM in the human embryo has not yet been described. We thus
>   immunolabeled consecutive sagittal sections of a **CS 16 embryo**<sup>**†**</sup> for GnRH
>   and doublecortin (DCX) (Fig. 1D,E,G), a marker of immature migratory
>   neurons (Gleeson et al., 1999). We identified a very small number (50
>   in total) of immature GnRH-expressing cells in the nasal mesenchyme,
>   in the medial portion of the olfactory placode (Fig. 1C-E), adjacent
>   to the basal lamina of the VNO, showing that the acquisition of cell
>   identity occurs outside the VNO between GW 5 and 6. At this stage, we
>   observed a mixed mass of immature GnRH neurons expressing DCX (Fig.
>   1F,G) or βIII-tubulin (Fig. 1H-J), migrating across the nasal
>   mesenchyme towards the telencephalon. As in rodents (Miller et al.,
>   2010), GnRH neurons in humans only represented a small proportion of
>   the MM (Fig. 1G). Furthermore, these **pioneer neurons** of the MM
>   expressed the delta/notch-like EGF repeat containing (DNER) (Fig.
>   1H-J), a transmembrane protein specifically localized in the dendrites
>   and cell bodies of postmitotic neurons.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>†</sup><sub>Carnegie stage (CS) 16 = ∼39th day of gestation</sub>